# Constructor - cannot be applied to given types - required: no arguments

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked so many times but I didn't really still understand why am I facing this issue. Answers provided in the blogs and posts, are already implemented in my code and I am still facing this issue(or I am still not able to figure out why my code compilation is failing)

```
public class Utilities {
   public Client client = null;
   private static object x = null;

   public Utilities(Client client) throws Exception {
      this.client = client;
      //CODE GOES HERE
   }
}
```

I am calling this class in other files as, `Utilities utile = new Utilities(client);`
When I compiled this code, I am getting below error,

```
constructor Utilities in class Utilities cannot be applied to given types
required: no arguments
found: Client
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

After going through couple of forum posts and blogs, I added default contractor , now my code looks like,

```
public class Utilities {
   public Client client = null;
   private static object x = null;

   private Utilities() {
      super();
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   public Utilities(Client client) throws Exception {
      this.client = client;
      //CODE GOES HERE
   }
}
```

But still the same error. Any clue what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I strongly suspect you've got two classes called `Utilities`, and that your "other" one is the one the constructor *call* is referring to.

Comment: @JonSkeet That was my hunch too. The error here is saying that your `Utilities` class cannot accept a `Client`.

Comment: Utilities utile = new Utilities(client);  what is  "client" here ?

Comment: Did you save and recompiled your code? Are you sure you imported correct `Utilities` class? If you change name of `Utilities`, remove its `class` file and recompile it again what error you get? If it is the same then you probably using different `Utilities` then planned.

Comment: @JonSkeet I also agree.  Perhaps you should check your `import` statements

Comment: Do you really have a class named `object`? That's a bad choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the response. I will re-check my code and will see if there is any prob in import

Comment: @Bohemian - no its not object... I just have removed the actual name and typed it as object to hide the project details...

Comment: @Pshemo - Thanks a lot for the quick response. I had a two issue's in my code. 1. Yes, there was import problem. 2. Even after compiling the code, my eclips client was still using the old file. May be my client was not updating the file or some other issue with my client(deleting the class file and re-compiling the code worked). I am still beginner in Java and there is lot to learn here. Once again, thanks for providing the quick resolution.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and let me know:

```
public class Utilities {
   private Client client;
   private Object x;

   //this is the normal structure of a constructor in java classes
   public Utilities(Client client){
      this.client = client;
      //CODE GOES HERE
   }
}
```